# Hiding Chart.js line, but showing it's data in the tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using the Chart.js library to build a chart. Consider the following Chart.js line graph :

[image]

So, there are 2 datasets that are being used here, one for the red line and one for the green line. I want to hide one of these datasets e.g. the red one. This will result in the red line not showing which is what I want.

However, what I also want is that the tooltip should show data for both the datasets (including the hidden dataset).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `borderColor: 'transparent'` for the `dataset` that should be hidden. To still have the desired colored boxes rendered in the tooltip, you'll also have to define a corresponding [callback function](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.6.0/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks).

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3', 'Player 4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'OK',
      borderColor: 'green',
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      data: [32, 44, 29, 33]
    }, {
      label: 'NOK',
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      data: [26, 29, 35, 35],
      fill: false,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      callbacks: {
        labelColor: tooltipItem => {
          var color = tooltipItem.datasetIndex == 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
          return {
            borderColor: color,
            backgroundColor: color
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="150" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can we use this for a bar graph as well? Because even if we hide a bar, it will not vacate the space for the other bar to occupy.

Comment: @Zahid Sattar: I would choose a different approach for a bar chart, defining stacked bars and keep invisible values below zero while maintaining `yAxis.ticks.min` at zero. Try it and if you get stuck, post a new question to get help.